# how to apply if condition on data bound combobox?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to apply if condition on data bound combobox but my code is not working. my combobox are getting data  `ComboBox5.DataSource = table2,ComboBox6.DataSource = table2,ComboBox6.DisplayMember = "name"` from sql, My combobox has multiple names like "bob","sam","john" etc. I want to hide another combobox when i select "bob" else that comboboxes should visible. how should i do it?

```
Dim rv As Object = ComboBox3.Items.Cast(Of Object)().Where(Function(r) ComboBox3.GetItemText(r) = "bob").FirstOrDefault()

If ComboBox3.SelectedText = rv Then
    ComboBox5.Visible = False
    ComboBox6.Visible = False
ElseIf ComboBox3.SelectedText <> rv Then
    ComboBox5.Visible = True
    ComboBox6.Visible = True
End If
```

Comment: You are geting the object that haves the text 'bob' then you check against the Text instead the object ... or check the SelectedText against simply 'bob' or check rv against SelectedItem

Comment: can you explain in some more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that checks if a TextBox.Text value is in a Combobox.

```
    Dim fn As String
    For Each fn In cbType.Items
        If fn = tbType.Text Then
            Do the = Code from your project
            Return
        End If
    Next
    Dim fn2 As String
For Each fn2 In cbType.Items
    If fn2 <> tbType.Text Then
        Do the <> Code from your project
        Return
    End If
Next
```